# FindResource API returns NULL for when read multiple resource one by one

Tags: c++, winapi

I have developed a dynamic library, in dll I have added a two resource text file, then through a executable I am dynamically loading the dll, when the call goes to FindResource API to first one,it works fine.Now i want to get reference to another one(i.e. second one) it gives me error 1814 i.e. resource name can't found.for both i have same resource type,pass different parameter of resource name (one those generated when i added resource file).
I tried for executable it is working.

//Code

```
char  sResNameDesign[5]  = _T("#101");
char sResNameIM[5]  = _T("#102");
//changes resource name to capital.
char sRestype[25] = _T("DESIGNXMLMAPPATH");



hMod = LoadLibrary("eastmoni.dll");

hresDesign = FindResource(hMod, sResNameDesign, sRestype);
hresIM = FindResource(hMod,sResNameIM,sRestype);
    if (hresDesign == NULL || hresIM == NULL)
{ 
   return RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND;
}

//.RC file

IDR_DESIGNXMLMAPPATH1   DESIGNXMLMAPPATH        "..\\..\\Resources\\Design.map"
IDR_DESIGNXMLMAPPATH2   DESIGNXMLMAPPATH        "..\\..\\Resources\\IMLookInfo.map"

//.Generated resource.h 

#define IDR_DESIGNXMLMAPPATH1           101
#define IDR_DESIGNXMLMAPPATH2           102
```

Comment: Can you please add a short code snippet, that we can see what API you are using.

Comment: Post excerpt of your DLL RC file, where you declare the two resources

Comment: The last comment on [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx) indicates, that resource names must be in all capital letters, or the function will fail. This likely applies to the resource type as well, i.e. `TCHAR sRestype[] = _T( "DESIGNXMLMAPPATH" );`.

Comment: I copy/pasted your code, verbatim, in some project and everything works fine. You may double check that the ..\..\Resources directory is the intended one. Search a folder where there is only Design.map ...

Comment: In my case ,for hresDesign return pointer correctly, but not hresIM returning NULL.  I also tried out only for                        hresIM = FindResource(hMod,sResNameIM,sRestype);                                   commenting hresDesign = .. statement but it doesn't work.As I said it worked fine when i did in .exe.

Comment: If anything resource related works in an .exe but not in a .dll chances are that you failed to pass the correct `HMODULE`. You also should **never** `LoadLibrary` a relative path name. This will only cause pain.